# Mongoose response from server is ReadableStream

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an express server that is fetching data from a local MongoDB.

The fetching seems to work and I am able to log the fetched data:

```
app.get("/getTestData", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await ContentDataSchema.find();
  console.log(`Mongo data: ${data})`);
  res.json(data);
});
```

This prints on the server console the correct data from DB which is expected to be an array of objects of the `ContentDataSchema`.

However, when trying to get this data from the client side:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:7007/getTestData")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(`RESPONSE ${response.body}`)
        
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(`SERVER ERROR ${error})`));
  }, []);
```

Console output from this is `RESPONSE [object ReadableStream]`
And if I tried to to log console.log(`RESPONSE ${JSON.stringify(response.body)}`)
Then the output is just {}.
Using Postman I can see the correct expected response calling the same endpoint.

Expected output on the client side would be the actual json from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the JSON response, you have to use the response.json() method. You can refer to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) about fetch to learn more about it.

```
    fetch("http://localhost:7007/getTestData")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: ur totally right, thanks mate!...too many working hours :D, thanks for the docs too

Comment: Not a problem :)